# Voice to Text in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

One of my clients is seeking functionality of Voice to text in SharePoint.

Is it available in SharePoint or by any third party tool?

Answer (score 1):

I remember that there is a namespace available for that

Try using `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition`

You can get more info on `Microsoft.Speech` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362881(v=office.14).aspx)

There is also an api provided by Microsoft, check it out 
[here](http://www.bing.com/dev/speech)

Also read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380027/Csharp-Speech-to-Text) (can use in webpart) , [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx#tab=server)

That would be a good place to start with